# Fine-tuning VGG-Face for Facial Expression Recognition on FER2013 - Grayscale vs RGB Images

Tags: conv-neural-network, data-preprocessing, computer-vision, transfer-learning

I am experimenting with Facial Expression Recognition and want to use a pretrained CNN model and a multi-stage fine tuning strategy to deal with scarce data. I came across the work of [Knyazev et al. (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.04598). The authors fine tune a [VGG-Face](http://eecs.csuohio.edu/%7Esschung/CIS660/DeepFaceRecognition_parkhi15.pdf) Face Recognition model on the [FER2013](https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/FER-2013) Facial Expression Recognition dataset. Unfortunately, they don't explain how they fine-tune a model trained on RGB images on a grayscale image dataset.

Is it possible (and practical) to fine tune a CNN originally trained on RGB images on a target dataset consisting of grayscale images? What is the general approach?

Comment: I found a similar question on Stackoverflow - [How can I use a pre-trained neural network with grayscale images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51995977/how-can-i-use-a-pre-trained-neural-network-with-grayscale-images). The suggestion is to convert the grayscale images to RGB. But I imagine this will greatly alter the input distribution and can't imagine it working well. Could anybody recommend literature  on the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to resize the images into a format that is no smaller than 197*197, and to recolor the images also.